# Can I add a UsingStatement using a Roslyn DocumentEditor

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

My Visual Studio extension needs to make multiple updates to a source code file. Using the DocumentEditor (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.DocumentEditor) class seems to be the recommended way to do this.

One of the changes may be to insert a using statement.

I can generate a UsingStatementSyntax with the following code:

```
public UsingDirectiveSyntax UsingStatement ( string  namespaceName )
{
  var qualifiedName = SyntaxFactory.ParseName ( namespaceName ) ;
  var usingSmnt     = SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective ( qualifiedName ) ;
  return usingSmnt ;
}
```

What I have tried to do, is to get the CompilationUnitSyntax from the Document object ...

```
  var Tree      = await RoslynDoc.GetSyntaxTreeAsync() ;
  var Root      = Tree.GetRoot() ;
  var cus       = Root as CompilationUnitSyntax ;
```

and to add the Using statement with **InsertBefore()**

```
  var usingSmnt = UsingStatement ( namespaceName ) ;
  RoslynEditor.InsertBefore ( cus.Members.First(), usingSmnt ) ;
```

At this point, it does not generate an error, but when I finally call the **GetChangedDocument()** method on the DocumentEditor, it results in an InvalidCastException (cannot cast UsingDirectiveSyntax to MemberDeclarationSyntax)

I know that I can add the UsingDirectiveSyntax to the CompilationUnitSyntax with the **AddUsings()** method, but I would prefer to make all changes via the DocumentEditor object if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add `UsingDirectiveSyntax` type to list of `MemberDeclarationSyntax` type

Change the insert statement to this and it will work:

```
RoslynEditor.InsertBefore(compilationUnit.Usings.First(), usingSmnt);
```

Comment: Hello Dudi, thanks for this answer, which usually works fine. However, it fails if the Usings list is empty. What could I do if the list is empty?

Comment: I was also working on something that required me to add using statements and I hit the same problem where if none existed, it would fail. I managed to find a solution that would work for both scenarios:  
  

```var updatedCompilationUnit = compilationUnit.AddUsings(usingStatement);
editor.ReplaceNode(compilationUnit, updatedCompilationUnit);```

Hope this helps!